# How to move Embedded Fields out of their embedded document?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Here is an example of one of my JSON docs:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "SongId": 1,
    "Details": {
        "Artist": "Cyndi Lauper",
        "Album": "She's So Unusual",
        "ReleaseYear": 1983
    },
    "SongTitle": "Girls Just Want To Have Fun"
}
```

How would one write a query to move the location of **"Artist"** and it's value out of the **"Details"** document, leaving "Album" & "ReleaseYear" still embedded.

Comment: not clear what you are trying to do here... please clarify your question

Comment: I changed it a little for you @AnthonyWinzlet.                                                        
     I am trying to move "Artist" field to be outside the "details" document but the "Album" and "ReleaseYear" should stay within that document. I know it's a basic query, but I've only been learning MongoDB for a few days.

Comment: Ok so do you want to update your document or need to get something like that?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to updating the name of a field, the [`$rename` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) can be used to move fields out of (or into) embedded documents.

When working with fields in embedded documents you need to use [*dot notation*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to refer to the field name.

Assuming a collection name of `discography`, you could move your `Details.Artist` field using:

```
db.discography.update(
    {_id: 1},
    {$rename: { "Details.Artist": "Artist"}}
)
```

Example result:

```
> db.discography.findOne({_id: 1})
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "SongId" : 1,
    "Details" : {
        "Album" : "She's So Unusual",
        "ReleaseYear" : 1983
    },
    "SongTitle" : "Girls Just Want To Have Fun",
    "Artist" : "Cyndi Lauper"
}
```

Comment: This is it!! Thank you so much @stennie! Now I thik dot notation is starting to make more sense to me.